# How do I share .zip file using UIActivityViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to share a .zip file via email / iTunes / other ways (such as message, AirDrop). I can already send a zipped file via email and iTunes, but when I try to send the zip file using UIActivityViewController, it doesn't show any file.

This is the code:

```
-(void) sendAllToApp {
    NSString *dpath=NSTemporaryDirectory();
    NSString *zipfile=[dpath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"All_Reports_of_Project_%@.zip",project.displayName]];
    [SSZipArchive createZipFileAtPath:zipfile withFilesAtPaths:zippedURL];//zipfile is the path that I store zip file data,zippedURL is the paths of files t.
    NSData *zipData=[[NSFileManager defaultManager]contentsAtPath:zipFile];
    NSURL *url =[NSURL fileURLWithPath:zipfile];
    [zipData writeToURL:url atomically:NO];
    if(zipData != nil) {
        UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[url] applicationActivities:nil];
        activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypePrint];
        if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
            activityViewController.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = self.navigationController.view;
            activityViewController.popoverPresentationController.sourceRect = CGRectMake(self.navigationController.view.bounds.size.width/2, self.navigationController.view.bounds.size.height/4, 0, 0);
        }
        [self.navigationController presentViewController:activityViewController animated:true completion:nil];

        activityViewController.completionWithItemsHandler = ^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed, NSArray *returnedItems, NSError *activityError) {
            // When completed flag is YES, user performed specific activity

                    };
        [self clearTmpDirectory];
    }
    else {
        [self showError];
        [self clearTmpDirectory];
    }
}
```

I set items to `@[url]` and `@[zipData]` both.

- When using URL, I can't use AirDrop.
- When using zip data, I get a .data file in my MacBook. If I change the .data file to .zip, it will become the correct file that I want to share.

So how can I share the .zip file correctly?

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue. The only fix that did work for us was to convert the .zip to a .tar file, which can be shared using a NSURL containing its path.